# C#: Reading Huge CSV File

Tags: c#, csv

I'm parsing a 40MB CSV file.

It works nicely right now, and it's rather easy to parse, the only problem I have is performance, which of course is rather slow.

I'd like to know if there is a way I can improve this, as I only need to find by key I find and then stop looping, so if the entry is at the beginning of the file it finishes quickly, but if it's at the end it takes a while.

I could balance this by giving it a random start line, but the algorithm would still be O(n)... So I'm not sure if it's really worth it.

Is there a way I can improve my sequential parsing algorithm?

Comment: If you could sort the file by that key, you could improve the speed quite a bit using a binary search.

Comment: First off, 40MB is not all that large for a CSV file.  Second, what's the code that you're currently using that's apparently taking so long?  I wouldn't think that it would be *that* slow, meaning you either have unrealistic expectations, or there's some more serious problem in your code.

Comment: Well the problem itself is just me wondering if I could make it run faster, it runs in ~1 second.

Comment: 1 second? Why would you want faster than a second

Comment: I just want to know if there is a possible faster way, because I'm curious? :-(

Comment: Why don't you post your code so people can make some suggestions.  Saying "how do I make it run faster?" without saying what IT is, doesn't give a lot to go on.

Answer (score 4):

First: "Reading Huge CSV File" and "So I'm parsing a 40MB CSV file.". Ihave space delimited files here of 10+ GIGAbyte - what would you call those?

Also: the size of the file is irrelevant, you process them normally anyway line by line.

> the only problem I have is performance, which of course is rather slow

Define. What do you think is slow? Parsing them is quite fast when done properly.

> I'd like to know if there is a way I can improve this, as I only need to find by key I find and 
>   then stop looping, so if the entry is at the beggining of the file it
>   finishes quickly, but if it's at the end it takes a while.

Do NOT use a CSV file? More than 60 years ago people invented databases for this.

> Is there a way I can improve my secuential parsing algorithm?

YOu mean except pulling the parsing into a separate thread, and using an efficient code (which you may not have - noone knows).

Theoretically you could:

- Read on one thread, with a decent buffer (less IO = faster)
- Move field split into thread 2 (optional)
- Use tasks to parse the fields (one per field per line) so you use all processors).

I am currently processing some (around 10.000) files (with sizes in double digit gigabte sadly) and... I go this way (Have to process them in a specific order) to use my computer fully.

That should give you a lot - and seriously, a 40mb file should load in 0.x seconds (0.5 - 0.6).

STILL that is very inefficient. Any reason you do not load the file into a database like all people do? CSV is good as some transport format, it sucks as a database.

Comment: While all of the improvements here can be useful, it's worth emphasizing to the OP that in your specific case, this will be a LOT  of work to get right, and you'll see very little improvement (on the order of a few tenths of a second maximum) because you just don't have enough data or processing demands.

Comment: On top, and that is what I say too, this is actually something that requires an INDEX and a DATABASE like approach - doing that from a CSV just is not the right approach to start with.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you convert your csv to a normal database. Even sqlexpress will be fine.

Comment: Well the CSV file is dropped by the client, they export it from excel and update it regularly, I could check for the file modified date and create a database if it was updated. It is a solution, although not the one I'm looking for, if the CSV becomes way too slow I might try this :)

Answer (score 3):

Of course.

Say you order it alphabetically.
Then, start in the middle.
Each iteration, move to the middle of the top or bottom; whichever has the appropriate key.

This algorithm has O(log *n*).

This is called a "binary search," and is what "Mike Christianson" suggests in his comment.

Comment: Ah! Ordered CSVs... This would work, but the CSV file isn't ordered, and parsing the file to order it might won't be worth it, as I could just do as @Lakis said. But I like this idea :)

Answer (score 1):

Will suggest you to break one 40Mb File into smaller size few files. 
And using  [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx) you could improve file processing performace

Comment: I didn't even know that was possible, eventhough the algorithm itself is still O(n) this would compute faster because of parallelism :) I will try this! Thanks!

Comment: If your file is on a single HD, it's likely that this will actually slow things down.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the CSV into DataTable and use available operations that could be faster than looping through

Loading it to database and perform your operation on that is another option

Answer (score 0):

This, I believe, is the fastest way to read a CSV file sequentially.  There may be other ways to extract data from CSV, but if you limited to this approach, then this solution might work for you.

```
const int BUFFER_SIZE = 0x8000;  //represents 32768 bytes
public unsafe void parseCSV(string filePath)
{
     byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
     int workingSize = 0; //store how many bytes left in buffer
     int bufferSize = 0; //how many bytes were read by the file stream
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
     char cByte; //character representation of byte
     using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
     {
         do
         {
              bufferSize = fs.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
              workingSize = bufferSize;
              fixed (byte* bufferPtr = buffer)
              {
                   byte* workingBufferPtr = bufferptr;
                   while (workingSize-- > 0)
                   {
                        switch (cByte = (char)*workingBufferPtr++)
                        {
                            case '\n':
                                break;
                            case '\r':
                            case ',':
                                builder.ToString();
                                builder.Clear();
                                break;
                            default:
                                builder.Append(cByte);
                                break;
                        }
                   }
              }
         } while (bufferSize != 0);
     }
}
```

Explanation:

- Reading the file into a byte buffer.  This will be done using the basic `Filestream` class, which gives access to the always fast `Read()`
- Unsafe code.  While I generally recommend not using unsafe code, when traversing any kind of buffer, using pointers can bring a speedup.
- `StringBuilder` since we will be concatenating bytes into workable strings to test againt the key.  StringBuilder is by far the fastest way to append bytes together and get a workable string out them.

Note that this method fairly complaint with [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), but if you deal with quotes, you can easily modify the code I posted to handle trimming.

Comment: I am not sure - seriously. THis may be fastest in the "cent wise and pound foolish" category and you ignore the fact that not all fields may be strings (I.e. additional conversion may be required). At the end you may save a LOT on - very little (the string split). I would go with a BUfferedStream on a FileStream (nie big buffer, like half a megabyte), use string split and then take it from there - assuming most fields get PARSED and the result into a class ;)

Comment: @TomTom I did some rudimentary testing on a 104MB CSV.  The way I presented the solution was actually the slowest performer (by approx 5%).  Safe code (array indexing) and safe code with buffered stream (512KB buffer) were faster and about equal.  I am unsure what you are referring to with string split, as it is string manipulation and conversions would still be required.

Comment: Exactly this is what I refer to. As MOST time will be spend in convesions and string manipulation, saving even 50% on the load will simply make zero effective difference ;) Premature optimization. Unsafe code for no real gain, i think (not checked). Depends a lot how complex the parsing is.